# Make the install package available for download after a transform

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline in Azure Devops. It has 3 stages.

My build creates an artifact with a web deploy package.

In stage 1 it is doing a deploy to a IIS on a local machine running an Azure Agent. This works great. I also do a variable transform on the connection string.

The next stage is to deploy to Pre Prod. BUT this machine is not available to me so the actual deploy is done by emailing/FTP the install package to the customer. So what I need is to run a transform and make the WebDeploy.zip file available for me to download.

In other words: I like to be able to download 2 packages with the correct transformed settings. PreProd.zip and Prod.zip

Stage 3 is like stage 2 but with Prod variables.

Comment: What kind of application it is? dotnet core app?

Comment: Yes dot net core

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your app and appsettings.json look like. But you may prepare one package for all envs at once. Using check section JSON configuration provider [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configuration-providers). Then you need only set (or ask to set) `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` envrioment variable.

So you need three files:

- appsettings.dev.json
- appsettings.preprod.json
- appsettings.prod.json

I'm not sure how you already solve transformation but you can fo instance use [token replace task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) for this:

your preprod config may look like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "#{Preprod.ConnectionString}#"
  },
}
```

and your prod file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "#{Prod.ConnectionString}#"
  },
}
```

Now if you add `PreprodConnectionString` and `Prod.ConnectionString` variables in your pipeline you will get token replace with variables values. In that way you can reuse the same package accros all enviroments.

**EDIT:**

You can also consider using [Secure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops). Please check also [`DownloadSecureFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops)task.

**EDIT**

Another option is [JSON variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution) it is like token replace but done just before deployment so file with secrets is not stored as an artifact.

Comment: I understand. I try not to use the extra appsettings files since I dont like how they are stored on the Git as well. Would hope to only have them in the build pipeline. This reminds me of the old web.confg and I never liked those.

Comment: It is not bad to keep them in source control. It is bad to keep secrets there. And this works totally different than `good old web.config` because here you don't do real transformation, you have them all in your package an at runtime a file for given env is selected. I would recommedn you to put just token in files and feed files on build.

Comment: Does a password in a connection string not count as a secret?

Comment: For sure I will consider this as a secret. This is why I show you how you can replace them or use Secure File. Do you have any doubt?

Comment: I added info about JSON Variable substitution. Maybe this is sth what your are looking for.

Comment: @Jepzen do you still have an issue?

Answer (score 0):

For web deploy package, there is xx.SetParameters.xml file that stores the necessary value, so you could update this file in these stage, then send necessary files to target server through FTP/SSH/Email etc...

[Configuring Parameters for Web Package Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment)

On the other hand, for the ASP.NET core project, the setting file per to environment variable is the better and easy way. (Krzysztof's reply)

Update 1:

There are some extensions that can be used for transform. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=transform&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Such as: [XDT Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform)

Comment: My solution is dot net core. I dont plan to add XML settings as well

Comment: @Jepzen How do you generate web deploy package?

Comment: With a DotNetCoreCLI@2 task. command: publish publishWebProjects: True. The first step is IIS deployemnt where it will set the connections string so i am looking for a task that just do the transform and leave the artifact hanging for me to grab it.

Comment: @Jepzen There are some extensions that can be used for transform. Check the update of my reply.

Comment: @Jepzen Do you solve the issue with either of these extensions?